# App size on Google App Engine and Multi-Player Unity Game Architecture

Tags: google-app-engine, unity-game-engine

I am developing an app which is a multiuser game. My app is to be run on the browser. So here my unity file talks to the database through the SFS server. This is the typical architecture that my application follows. My current app size is about 47MB.

Now I am trying to upload the app to the Google App Engine. I made a few smaller (in size) demos and tried uploading them and they worked fine. But just realized that my current app does not upload as it exceeds the 32MB quota. Is there a way to still make my file work (other than reducing the file size)?

Also, will the mentioned architecture (Unity-SFS-MySQL) work fine on GAE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you hit the maximum deployment limit of 32MB per file (total is 1GB). See [deployment quotas](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Deployments).

Do you have a file in your project that is bigger than 32MB? Can you split it in smaller files? If not, than you might need to [upload your file to blobstore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Uploading_a_Blob) and [serve it from there](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Serving_a_Blob).